# Different web server on one domain

Tags: wordpress, yesod, subdirectory

I have two web sites:

- (a) is built with yesod web framework (and running on port A)
- (b) is built with wordpress (and running on port B)

I want to publish these sites as following:

- `foo.com/wp` refers to (b)
- Other pages on `foo.com` refers to (a)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use (a) and (b) behind a proxy (c) -- NGINX is my personal preferred server for that purpose because it is insanely fast and good on resources.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy

You'd do something like this:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:{port for a}/;
    }

    location /wp {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:{port for b}/;
    }
}
```

** note that {b} will know that it is at /wp. If you need the backend server to think that it's at root (/), you can do it with a rewrite (also in the NGINX docs)